# Using Google Apps for Work account to sign in to access Azure portal

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, azure-active-directory, google-account

In our organization, we are using Google Apps for Work for emails, calendar, document repository.
We also have some other services that we are using our google account to authenticate with SSO support. Simply google account is our SSO account that we want to use in all services we are using.

There are few exceptional services that we were not able to setup Google as identity provider. One of them is Azure Services. In azure, you can provision Azure Active Directory and create accounts in it and use that accounts to access many other Azure Services, such as Azure SQL Databases. If you are using Visual Studio Team Service, you can also configure VSTS to backed by AAD, then you can access to VSTS using AAD Account.

My question is, is there a way to configure AAD to delegate authentication on google side ?

If we can do this, then we would be able to use our Google Account to access all azure services

Comment: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/10483017-sso-sign-in-to-azure-via-google-apps-idp

If this is what you are asking for, guess it's still under review.

Comment: Yes @alwayslearning, this was exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Microsoft services pretty much don't support any accounts other than Azure AD & Microsoft Account at this time.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up Azure AD as the Identity Provider for your Google Apps account.  I'm sure there would be some tedious steps in the process to get your users moved over but it should work.  When your users attempt to login to Google Apps they would get redirected to an Azure AD sign in page and then redirected back to Google.

Some marketing material can be found here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/partners/google/googleapps/